# Login to Vault using LDAP - Operation Failed

Tags: ldap, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to configure authentication based on LDAP with Vault, however, when trying to login, I am getting Status 400 with Ldap Operation Failed.

```
vault write auth/ldap/config url=“ldap://192.165.165.68:10389” userdn=“ou=users,ou=system,dc=myorg,dc=com” binddn=“uid=admin,ou=system,dc=myorg,dc=com” bindpass=“secret” userattr=“uid” insecure_tls=true starttls=false
```

When tried login, I am gettng following response:

```
[mftadmin@host01v amf]$ vault login -method=ldap username=user1
Password (will be hidden):
Error authenticating: Error making API request.

URL: PUT http://ldaphost:8200/v1/auth/ldap/login/user1
Code: 400. Errors:

ldap operation failed
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

Have you created this username previously?

`vault write auth/ldap/users/user1 groups="group1"`